# How to mirror a github repository, while maintaining my small changes?

Tags: git, github

I have to create a mirror of a github repository, and make small changes to it.

The owner of the original will not pull in my changes, so I have to keep a mirror of it and maintain any updates of the original, yet keep my very minor changes at the same time.

What would be the best way to do this?

Is it a manual process, so I setup email notifications on the original repo, and then whenever there is a change, what do I do to pull in the updates and make sure my stuff doesn't get written over?

Comment: Shouldn't `git fetch other/master` followed by (on your `master` branch) `git merge other/master` automatically take care of everything?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this before, but what about this approach:

1. Lets say you have forked a repo into your repo. There version was Version1
2. On this Version1 you apply your changes. Let's say 2 changes on 2 different files. I'm doing those changes in 2 commits. (let's call them Commit1 and Commit2)
3. Then my changes and Version1 are merged on the master branch, resulting in MyVersion1
4. the repo you are mirroring has a new version: Version2. You are notified.
5. you mirror Version2 into a staging branch. On this branch you cherry-pick Commit1 and Commit2 (it's hard for me to estimate what small changes you are talking about on what files of the original repo, but this could work). Then you do some integration testing from this branch
6. merge the staging branch in master.

Let me know if this might suit you and then I can go into more detail on the git commands.